# How to arduino code to separate strings and integers sent from bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino-uno

How to code to separate strings and integers sent from bluetooth to control the servo and led. I send 'a' and 'b' for on / off led, while integer 1-90 to move servopos? This is my code where is the mistake?

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#include <Servo.h>
Servo servo;


int bluetoothTx = 10;
int bluetoothRx = 11;
char data = 0;
SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx);

void setup() 

{
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  servo.attach(9);
  //setup usb serial connection to computer
  Serial.begin(9600);  
  bluetooth.begin(9600);
   delay(100);
  //setup bluetooth serial connection to android
}


void loop() 
{
  if(Serial.available() > 0)  
  { 
     data = Serial.read();      
    Serial.print(data);        
    if(data == 'a')            
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);  
    else if(data == 'b')       
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);   
    if(bluetooth.available()> 0 )
  {   

    int servopos = bluetooth.read();
    int servopos1;

    servopos1 = servopos + 4 ;

    Serial.println(servopos);
    servo.write(servopos1);

  }} 
}
```

Comment: whixh error are you getting?

Comment: Suggestion: use all integers. Positive for the servo angle, and negative for the LED (i.e.: -1 = LED on and -2 = LED off)

Comment: If I send 'a' or 'b' for on / off led, the servo moves. How do I prevent the servo from moving when I send 'a' or 'b'? @Ogabe

Comment: If i send integer -1 and -2 to led servo come move @ModularSynth

Comment: No. You should check the case. If the int < 0 then act on the LED. Else act on the servo. EASY.

Comment: Oke, Thanks. Can you help me write in arduino code? @ModularSynth

Comment: Too broad a question.

Comment: sorry @ModularSynth

Comment: It's OK. I didn't get harmed from that.